# Workbook opens but I still get a VBA Subscript out of range error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to open a workbook through my marco script and I have this error recurring everytime I try to open a workbook. The problem I'm facing is that when I use

```
Workbooks.Open (strFilePath)
```

where,

```
strFilePath = "genericfilepath\FileDuplicate.xlsx"
```

The script launches the workbook but I still get a Subscript out of range error. I've also tried to turn of alerts by putting my code in between

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
.
.
Workbooks.Open (strFilePath)
.
.
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I've also tried On Error Resume Next to no avail, the workbook launches but I still get a pop error msg.

Comment: What is your full code? and what line do you get the error on?

Comment: The line that I get the error is the one above, If I manually open the workbook and skip this particular line while debugging the rest of my code works just fine. This particular line fails on different places on my code, the workbook launches but I still get a pop up and the script stops.

Comment: Try `Dim wb as Workbook` and use `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(...`

Comment: Thanks Matt! You have no idea how relieved I am.

Comment: @MattCremeens, can you add that as an answer with a blurb about why you need to `Set` (or not use the `()` version of `Open`)?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a workbook opened with vba, you need to `Set` a reference to it, like so

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(string of path and filename)
```

Then  you can go on referencing the `Workbook` object, `wb` and use its methods and refer to its properties.

Comment: If you do not need the `Workbook` object, you can also just use `Workbooks.Open "path to file"` with no parentheses (and with no preceding `Dim` line).  This calls `Open` and discards the return, which is valid.  (So in OP's example, you could just remove the `()` and it would run.  OP probably got the `subscript out of range` error trying `Workbooks("path to file")`.

Comment: @ByronWall There is no issue with the `()` - a statement such as `abc = ("xyz")` is equivalent to the statement `abc = "xyz"` and, in this case, `Workbooks.Open (strFilePath)` is equivalent to `Workbooks.Open strFilePath`.